# What does this diagonal line in the drums sheet music mean?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, drums

As the title says, what does the indicated line in the figure mean in a drum sheet music?

[image: slashes written above — and stemmed with — eighth notes on bottom space of staff]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a rather overzealous notation for a rim click, which is more typically notated as a regular note head with a diagonal line through it (among other options)<sup>1</sup>. It goes with the indication just above that "R.H. plays the rim of the rack tom", and the slashes show when to play — every eighth note.

---

<sup>1</sup> See Elaine Gould, *Behind Bars* (Faber, 2011), page 295.

Comment: Would say given the text notation that it's not a rim *shot*, which is when the stick strikes the rim and head simultaneously and is quite a loud sound. It's just another notehead, and in my experience, there really isn't a standard convention for what notehead means what in percussion notation.

Comment: @Tristan Yeah, "rim shot" was the wrong term. Thanks.